# Control keyboard LEDs

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, led

I have an IdeaPad G560 and it has a bunch of LEDs on the keyboard. I would like to use some of these. Where should I look for files controlling these? There's no led directory in /proc/acpi (where it was on my previous laptop, in the asus directory) or in /sys/class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a program called `ledd`.  Lets you program blinking sequences and change them on the fly.

At least on my Poweredge 2500 server, the leds are controlled through the console driver.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you start here:

> http://www.helpowl.com/manuals/Lenovo/G560/66125

Or the direct [link here](http://consumerdl.lenovo.com.cn/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User%27s%20guides%20and%20manuals/G460-G560/G460%26G560%20UserGuide%20V1.0%20EN%20147002899-1.1%20(10.03.18)_web.pdf) (no signup needed)

See page 13.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here, please expand your answer. *Welcome to Super User!*